# Return multiple values in jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jQuery post function that returns a response on success after the click of a `div`. However, I would like to return multiple variables on success. Do I have to use JSON, and if so, is it possible to integrate it into the `$.ajax` function after *success*?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: "action=favorite&username=" + username + "&topic_id=" + topic_id + "&token=" + token,
   url: "favorite.php",
   success: function(response) {

   }
});
```

---

**EDIT**
I appreciate everyone's help + 1 to all!

Comment: On success, everything is happening on the page the request is done from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be a very good idea to use only JSON responses from the server. That way your server backend would act as a JSON-RPC server and the front-end would be completely independent of it! Of course you can use JSON with the `$.ajax` function. Here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://some.url.com/',
    data: 'some=post&data=xyz',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response, statusText) {
        // `response` here is a valid JSON object; jQuery handles the work of parsing the response, etc.
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, if the response is NOT valid JSON, the function specified in the `error` parameter is called and passed the `xht` object, `statusText` and the `response`. Check jQuery documentation on more details.

Comment: Another point: It is not considered safe to use the `eval()` function for parsing responses directly. Also, instead accessing parameters like `jsonobj.someparameter` it usually considered more safe to do `jsonobj['someparameter']`.

Comment: what do you mean by JSON-RPC server and what are the benefites of having this?

Comment: ps I used your suggestion and it worked, I didn't know you could do that without $get.json! What is the difference of this function and the one you suggested?

Comment: @Scarface: JSON-RPC allows you to pass commands and parameters to the server and get a response. It's very similar to what you're doing, except (as I understand it; I've never used it) it's JSON to the server, and JSON from the server.

Comment: @Scarface: @Jim's right about JSON-RPC. If you've used XML-RPC or SOAP interfaces or such (y'know, like the Twitter API), it's the same concept. Except its much more flexible (personal opinion) than XML-RPC. You make POST or GET requests to the server as you would normally do. The server responds in terms of objects instead of say plain-text or plain XML. These objects may even contain executable functions (although, again, that isn't a safe practice). `$get.json` is actually just a wrapper for `$.ajax` with `dataType` set to `json`.

Comment: PS: If you are a PHP guy, you might want to take a look at Zend Framework's implementation of the JSON-RPC server class.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a jquery post function that returns a response on success after the click of a div. 
>   However, I would like to return multiple variables on success.

You can only return one value - a blob of text (in most cases).

You can, however, structure that text, so you can easily extract different bits of data from it.

> Do I have to use JSON

No, but it is the simplest option.

> , and if so, is it possible to integrate it into the $.ajax function after success?

Umm. Yes. Did you read the manual for the [jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? It explicitly mentions using JSON and getting an object as the argument to the success function.

Comment: david how could you structure the text, just curious and when is it best to use json

Comment: @Scarface — as JSON, as XML, as CSV, as whatever format you like.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to return JSON (or some other data format supported by jQuery's ajax() function) from favorite.php.
**edit**: it doesn't *have* to be json, but for multiple return values, it is the easiest to parse. For instance, if you returned xml or html, you'd have to traverse nodes to return a value.

For instance, if you returned:
`{"user": "Joe", "success" : "pass", "message" : "favorite added" }`

in success, you would use:

```
function(response){
  var user = response.user;
  var success = response.success; // etc.
}
```

The important thing to remember is to specify the dataType in your ajax call as json.
jQuery also supports the other dataTypes: **xml, html, script, jsonp, text**

I believe the default is html. And, having written php to return xml with properly formatted headers in the php script, I can tell you that sometimes you **have** to specify the dataType for jQuery to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the returned json is something like this

```
{
  firstName: 'Ricardo',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  errors: 0
}
```

You can use the jQuery getJSON method as follows:

```
$.getJSON(
   'favorite.php',
   { 'action': 'favorite', 'username': username, 'topic_id': topic_id, 'token': token },
   function(data) {
     alert(data.firstName);
     alert(data.lastName);
     alert(errors);
   }
)
```

In the returning function you can get the many variables you want.

Comment: also, getJSON() is a wrapper around ajax() which specifies `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Just curious, I use php, to pass values in json, I am using this big file called json.php which allows me to use '$json->encode($data);' is there a way to encode without using an external document?

Comment: @Scarface: php has json_encode built in after 5.2 on default php installs.  see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

I have never programmed in PHP. In asp.net JSON is the default mode of data exchange in async webservice call , so as a developer I dont have to worry about underlying details of JSON. I guess even jQuery gets its data in JSON format. If in case you have multiple values , you can get them in the form of list or dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

To send some data to the page mentioned under 'url', you can do this using your 'data' section

`data: { _token: CSRF_TOKEN, prot_string : request.term, organism : 'homo sapience'}`
And from the page mentioned under url, these values can be taken as :
`$request->get('prot_string'); $request->get('organism');`