# json - Jquery return undefined for multiple values in ajax call

Tags: json, jquery

I want to return multiple values from Ajax call. So I modified my codes based on this page [Jquery return multiple values in ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571702/jquery-return-multiple-values-in-ajax-call)

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "AJAX_custom_function.aspx/AJAX_GetFullName",
     data: '{userid: "' + arguments.Value + '"}',
     dataType: "json",
     async: false,
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
         alert(data.fullname);    
     },
     error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
     }    
 });
```

'alert(data)' returns {"fullname": "Joe", "success" : "true"}

But 'alert(data.fullname)' returns undefined. The correct value should be Joe

Did I missing something? Any advice is very much appreciated.

AJAX_GetFullName

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function AJAX_GetFullName(ByVal userid As String) As Object

    Dim isValid As Boolean = False  'by default, user always not exist
    Dim strFullName As String = ""

    isValid = IsUserIDExist(userid, strFullName)
    If isValid Then
        Return "{'fullname': '" & strFullName & "', 'success': 'true' }"
    Else
        Return "{'fullname': '', 'success': 'false' }"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: please show me your `WebMethod` `AJAX_GetFullName` there is something wrong with the return type. because alert(data) should alert `object Object` if the `WebMethod` is correct.

Comment: @ChristopheCVB  Data type is string

Comment: @naveen You are right, the return type is string which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    url: "AJAX_custom_function.aspx/AJAX_GetFullName",
    data: '{"userid": "' + arguments.Value + '"}',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        try {
            // convert single quote to double quotes
            var msg = data.replace(/'/g, "\"");
            msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
            alert(msg.fullname);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.Message);
        }
    },
    error:function (xhr, status, err){
        alert( "status=" + xhr.responseText + ", error=" + err );
    }

});
```

No need to specify `dataType` and `charset` in `contentType`.

Comment: In between, it return false for data.hasOwnProperty("d")

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Not sure why, I cannot call any of these functions
$.parseJSON
jQuery.parseJSON
JSON.parse

The alert will stop working after I call any above function. So weird.

I am using jquery 1.4.2 . Does it matter ?

Comment: please paste your `AJAX_GetFullName` method

Comment: Edited. Please refer to above.

Comment: You are the man, problem solved.

My bad, I don't know is the single quote cause the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using :

```
success: function(data) {
    if (typeof data == 'string')
    {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    }
    alert(data.fullname);
}
```

Comment: After I run this line: data = JSON.parse(data), the alert stop working already

Comment: @Alfred: JSON is not natively supported in all browsers. you might wanna add a reference to http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js and since you are using jQuery its a lot better to use `$.parseJSON`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure why, I cannot call any of these functions $.parseJSON jQuery.parseJSON JSON.parse The alert will stop working after I call any above function. So weird. I am using jquery 1.4.2 . Does it matter ?

Comment: Strange :
version added: 1.4.1 - jQuery.parseJSON( json )

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string to Json object use JSON.parse(data) function with in the success function of Ajax call. i hope this will help.